# Paste first page and last page a document (docx) into another docx

Tags: vba, ms-word

i have some word files from which i am trying to extract the first and last page and copy into another document.

I have tried the following code i am able to get it partially working , the first page is copied to the new document , however i am not able to get the last page copy working as  the last page overwrites the first page copied. how do i move the courser to end page prior to last page is copied.

```
Sub getfirstlast()


Dim Counter As Long, Source As Document, Target As Document
Dim strFolderA As String
Dim strFileSpec As String
Dim strFileName As String
Dim objDocA As Word.Document

strFolderA = InputBox("Enter path to document:")
strFileSpec = "*.docx"
strFileName = Dir(strFolderA & strFileSpec)

Set objDocA = Documents.Add
 Documents.Open (strFolderA & strFileName)


Set Source = ActiveDocument
ActiveDocument.PageSetup.Orientation = wdOrientLandscape
Selection.HomeKey unit:=wdStory
Pages = Source.BuiltInDocumentProperties(wdPropertyPages)

Counter = 0
'MsgBox "number of pages:" & Pages

While Counter < Pages
   Counter = Counter + 1

 'first page
  If Counter = 1 Then
    Source.Bookmarks("\Page").Range.Copy
    Set Target = objDocA
    Target.Range.Paste

 End If

   'last page
   If Counter = Pages Then

    Source.Bookmarks("\Page").Range.Copy
    Set Target = objDocA
    Target.Activate
    Selection.EndKey unit:=wdStory
    Target.Range.Paste

 End If

Wend


Target.PageSetup.Orientation = wdOrientLandscape
Target.SaveAs FileName:=strFolderA & Replace(strFileName, ".docx", "_.docx")
Target.Close

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I've made some alterations to the code in the question in order to streamline the task.

What's supposed to happen with the path and file name information, as well as opening a document, wasn't clear in the context of a reproducible procedure. I commented out the `Documents.Open` line, but made a suggestion based on the assumption that this is supposed to be the source document. The code I tested uses the line below that, with `ActiveDocument`.

It's possible to jump directly to a particular page using the `GoTo` method. This will be faster than looping the pages, especially in a large document.

Using `GoTo` and the built-in `\Pages` bookmark require the `Selection` object and that the source document be the active one.

Writing to the Target, however, can use a `Range` object. Note that it's better to use a separate object, rather than `Document.Range` for this kind of work. Then, the trick is to `Collapse` the `Range` in order to add information (instead of replacing the range content).

While the Copy/Paste approach in the question does work, it's more efficient to work with the `Range.FormattedText` property to transfer content within or between Word documents. This also leaves the user's Clipboard content intact.

```
Sub getfirstlastPagesToNewDocument()
    Dim Counter As Long, Pages As Long, Source As Document
    Dim strFolderA As String
    Dim strFileSpec As String
    Dim strFileName As String
    Dim objDocA As Word.Document
    Dim rngTarget As Word.Range, rngSource As Word.Range

    strFolderA = InputBox("Enter path to document:")
    strFileSpec = "*.docx"
    strFileName = Dir(strFolderA & strFileSpec)
    '??SEt Source = Documents.Open (strFolderA & strFileName)
    Set Source = ActiveDocument
    Set objDocA = Documents.Add
    Set rngTarget = objDocA.content

    Source.PageSetup.Orientation = wdOrientLandscape
    Source.Activate
    Selection.HomeKey unit:=wdStory
    Pages = Source.BuiltInDocumentProperties(wdPropertyPages)

    Selection.GoTo What:=Word.wdGoToAbsolute, Which:=Word.wdGoToPage, Count:=1
    Set rngSource = Selection.Bookmarks("\Page").Range
    rngTarget.FormattedText = rngSource.FormattedText
'    Selection.Bookmarks("\Page").Range.Copy
'    rngTarget.Paste

    Selection.GoTo What:=Word.wdGoToAbsolute, Which:=Word.wdGoToPage, Count:=Pages
    Set rngSource = Selection.Bookmarks("\Page").Range
'    Selection.Bookmarks("\Page").Range.Copy
    rngTarget.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
    rngTarget.FormattedText = rngSource.FormattedText
'    rngTarget.Paste

    objDocA.PageSetup.Orientation = wdOrientLandscape
    objDocA.SaveAs fileName:=strFolderA & Replace(strFileName, ".docx", "_.docx")
    objDocA.Close

End Sub
```